# Upload image to Cloudinary via Lambda using node.js

Tags: node.js, lambda, serverless-framework, cloudinary

I'm working on a Serverless Webapp (node.js) and have come across a problem which has been blocking me now for 2 days.

Scenario:
- User comes to the site, uploads an image directly to our S3 bucket.
- Event is fired and is added to the AWS SQS queue ready for Lambda to pick up
- Lambda picks up the image key
- Lambda then connects to Cloudinary (via SDK)
- Lambda then tries to upload via the SDK command cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload('s3://bucket-name/file-name', (error, result) => { console.log(error, result)});

Problem:
Nothing gets uploaded to Cloudinary, no Errors are found in Cloudwatch, console.log is empty from callback.

The S3 bucket is whitelisted, I've created a file in my S3 .wellknown/cloudinary/cloud_name

index.js

```
import imageTransform from "./imageTransform";

exports.imageFromQueue = async event => {
  event.Records.forEach(async record => {
    const body = JSON.parse(record.body).Records[0];
    const { eventName, s3 } = body;
    if (eventName === "ObjectCreated:Post") {
      const { key } = s3.object;
      console.log("here", key); --> This gets printed out
      const data = await ImageTransform(key);
    }
  });
};

}
```

imageTransform.js

```
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
});

const ImageTransform = async imagePath => {
  try {
    const data = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
      `s3://${process.env.IMAGE_BUCKET}/${imagePath}`
    );

    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("cloudinary - major error", error);
    return { majorError: error };
  }
}
```

Comment: Add more logging, is `eventName` condition correct (`ObjectCreated:Post` vs `s3:ObjectCreated:Post`), are you extracting the right params from the event (going from records map to get first body record)? It sounds like `ImageTransform` isn't being executed at all.